# How can I get an error message when Language is not selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a website whose function is to translate subtitles from one language to another, translation is done using google widget tool , marked with red color on the image: https://ibb.co/LCWt6YV (as you can see on the left it says on google widget tool "Select Language")

there is also the option that the user can save the translated subtitle file to the database and the language in which the user translated the subtitle is automatically saved to the database,now many users do not know to use this option so they `do not choose the language` to translate the subtitle and just leave the option on google widget tool `"Select Language"`.

`I need some function/code so that no action will be done if Language is not chosen.`

That if he does not select a language through a google widget tool and tries to save subtitles in the database, the message "Please select a language before saving subtitle" appears.

This php script is for saving subtitles into a database, now which function/code I should add in this script ?

```
$data =  $_POST['data'];
$file_name =  $_POST['xxx'];
$subtitle =  $_POST['xxx'];
$language =  $_POST['xxx'];
$author =  $_POST['xxx'];
$ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $ip = array_pop(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
}


$data =json_decode($data, true);

foreach($data as $obj){

    $subtitles1->add($obj['start'], $obj['end'],$obj['text']);
    $subtitles1->save($file_name);
}
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$new_file_name_ext = time()."_".$sub."_".$lan.".".$ext;
$new_file_name = time()."_".$sub."_".$lan;
$sql_lan = "SELECT code FROM lan_code WHERE language ='$lan'";
$result_lan = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_lan);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_lan) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_lan)){
        $lan_code = $row['code'];
    }
}else{
    $lan_code = $lan;
}
$sub_new = $sub.'_'.$lan_code;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name ='$sub_new'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $data1 = "Unable to save subtitle, subtitle already exists with the same language in the database.";
}
else{
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO table (xxx , xxx, xxx, xxx, ip)
            VALUES ('$sub_new','$authors', '$lan', '$new_file_name', '$ip')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query1)){
        copy("$file_name", "uploads/$new_file_name_ext");
        //new GoodZipArchive('uploads/$new_file_name',    'upload/output_zip_file.zip') ;
        $data1 = "Successful, File saved to database.";

        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $new_zip = time()."_".$subtitles."_".$languages.".zip";
        if ($zip->open("uploadsk/$new_zip", ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
        {
            $zip->addFile("uploads/$new_file_name_ext", "$new_file_name_ext");
            $zip->close();
        }
    } else{
        $data1 = mysqli_error();
    }
}

echo $data1; ?>
```

Comment: Where is your definition for `$lan` in your SQL query ? Or is it `$language`?

Comment: Yes, it is $language sir !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pop up a message when no language is selected, you need to use Javascript.

In a very simplistic way you can use javascript alert() function, something like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
if(empty($language) or !isset($language)){
    echo 'alert("please select a language")';
}else{
   ...add the rest of your code here.
}
echo '</script>';
```

But this results in a very ugly output. If you want something prettier you can use a plugin like sweetAlert. It's very easy to use, and a lot better then simply "alert" your message. You can take a look to sweetAlert [here](https://sweetalert2.github.io/).

Good luck!

Comment: This results in "rest of your code" being outputed between script elements..

Comment: Hi Peyu, can you please insert that code into my script that I can have completed code (I dont want to mess something)? Thank you

Comment: @iccube, that's beacuase you are copynig and pasting. This answers show a path to a possible solution, but you must understand the code by your own.

Comment: @Angel666 I don't have an apache server right now (I haven't neither all your code) to test a fully functional code. Try to do it yourself and ask me again if you found any trouble. I will try to answer any question. Best Regards.